Общий элемент в сложном предложении с разными видами связи (союз И и бессоюзная связь)
Предложение из недавнего вопроса на форуме (с дополнением в комментарии):
Модели интересные(,) и цены невысокие, это настоящий Клондайк!

Модели интересные, и цены невысокие.  Запятая в ССП ставится, но откуда сомнения? Смысловое единство есть (по контексту, вероятно), а грамматического нет. Однородные отношения, перечислительная интонация.

Добавлено третье предложение, связь бессоюзная. Теперь есть общий элемент или нет?

Да и правильно ли построено сложное предложение в целом? У меня есть сомнения. Можем ли мы просто "приписать" третье предложение к двум имеющимся? Как его теперь читать (тоже с перечислением)?

Как можно записать это сообщение, чтобы оно выглядело естественно (можно менять структуру предложения)?
P. S. Дело не в конкретном предложении, а в 
модели для подобных предложений. Думаю, что 
"МОДЕЛЬНЫЙ ПРИНЦИП"  в грамматике — хороший 
вариант для практики письма. Он может заменить 
традиционные правила. Структурный принцип дается 
в Грамматике-80 — вот где следует искать 
БАЗИСНЫЕ МОДЕЛИ. А в нашем случае мы говорим 
скорее о частных МОДИФИКАЦИЯХ (три предикативные 
основы, сочинительная и бессоюзная связь).




Меня замучил этот "Клондайк"... ну никак он не вписывается в тему, где нужно тратить...
Ну да ладно.
Напишем так:
Модели интересные и цены невысокие – это настоящий Клондайк!
Почему бы нет? Смысл такой же, как в СПП:
Если модели интересные и цены невысокие, то это настоящий Клондайк!

Это БСП?  Розенталь не разрешает) К тому же по семантике Клондайк относится только к одному предложению. // Это присоединительная конструкция? А Розенталь разрешает присоединение считать общим элементом?) // А Клондайк я решительно delete to basket.

Да не важно, БСП это или ещё что-то. Для меня это как тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными целыми словосочетаниями и даже предложениями, цельными смысловыми единицами.

Для вас? Но мы обсуждаем грамматические модели. Вы рекомендуете свою модель в качестве образца? Основная модель весьма частотна, а ваша? Можно ли подобрать примеры из литературы, как вы думаете? // Здесь не словосочетания, а три предложения, ну и сочинительная связь между двумя.  //Я сначала думала про этот вариант, но чем-то он мне не нравился. Тире? А разве есть в этой теме тире. Стала смотреть Розенталя, и увидела препозицию общего элемента в БСП. А вот в СПП позиция неважна.

Я и говорю "и даже предложениями". Зачем примеры? Модель проста: два неразрывных простых предложения выступают единым подлежащим (как однородные члены), они характеризуются только вместе, с помощью сказуемого, их определения

Да я не спорю, может, и так. Будем наблюдать за практикой)  А пока мой голос за вашу МОДЕЛЬ. Можно ли  ее добавить к правилам Розенталя – вот о чем я спрашивала)

Правила Розенталя такие, что всё отовсюду вытекает... Думаю, "моя" модель согласуется с общей розенталевской концепцией.

В вашем предложении создаётся  впечатление, что первая часть приравнивается ко второй части.

@Серж Ну а смысл всего высказывания в чём? В том, что одно сравнивается с другим /приравнивается к чему-то / является чем-то / определяется тем или другим образом. Это есть это.

Смысл не в  том, что невысокие цены – это и есть клондайк, а в том, что автор выражает свою оценку тому, что цены невысокие. Здесь нет сравнения!

@Серж Да при чём тут сравнение или несравнение, называйте как хотите? Я же перечислил любые отношения, где одно характеризуется другим с помощью тире и слова "это".

Правильно:
Это хороший вариант: модели интересные и цены невысокие.
В предложении три предикативные основы, сочинительная и бессоюзная связь. В этом случае по Розенталю:
  2) Общей может быть придаточная часть сложноподчиненного 
  предложения: Уже совсем рассвело и народ стал подниматься, 
  когда я вернулся в свою комнату (Л. Т.); Когда он вернулся 
  в залу, сердце его билось и руки дрожали так заметно… 

  3) Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями 
  сложносочиненного предложения третья часть, предшествующая 
  им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью: Берегов не 
  видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны 
  разлива (М. Г.);

И никак иначе: то есть при бессоюзной связи общая часть находится в препозиции и обозначается двоеточием.
В чем принципиальная ошибка? При неоднородных отношениях предложение с тремя предикативными основами состоит из двух блоков, при этом знак препинания обозначает отношения между блоками. В данном случае это двоеточие как однозначный выбор.

Лучше оставить персональный вариант, чуть изменив его. Настоящий клондайк: модели интересные и цены невысокие.

Хотя первоначальный вариант более экспрессивный, но вы правы. У него перечислительная интонация.

@Серж.  Не лучше, у оценочной реплики  нет обобщающего смысла. Она относится только к ценам, а там прямой контакт с моделями. Правильная запись такая: Модели интересные, и цены невысокие.  Это настоящий Клондайк! // Запись  естественная, по слуху, вот и соединяют все в одно. Пользователи не понимают построения сложного предложения в принципе  и считают, что это просто сумма простых предложений. К сожалению, в школах уделяется недостаточное внимание грамматике. //  Да и хороших педагогов не так уж много. Работа тяжелая, люди уходят. Ну и дети современные не совсем адекватные))

Возможно, и в программе нет.  Ничего, если поступят на филфак, то все поймут. А остальным, думаю, это и не нужно. да и потом, что требовать от детей, когда порой видишь, что сами пеггоги по иностранному языку достаточно не владеют родным языком, ссылаясь на то, что они специалисты по иностранному языку.

@Серж, разве грамматика и знание языка нужны только будущим филологам? К примеру, если требуется «впарить» покупателям интересные модели, красно  говорить куда как необходимо))  Да и пишут сейчас везде и много, так что  письменную речь тоже нужно уметь правильно построить. Вот пример, на БВ задали вопрос. Там приведено предложение, а потом изменён порядок слов. И вопрос: чем варианты отличаются по смыслу? Вы как ответите?  Порядок слов проходят сейчас в школе? Не знаю, а если и проходят, то мимо.

Чтобы ответить на вопрос, нужно видеть предложение. А грамматика нужна всем, но вряд ли можно говорить о том, что многие изучают ее углубленно, даже люди с высшим образованием.

Вот вопрос:  Выражения "заставил себя ждать" и "себя ждать заставил", есть ли разница?  // Я же говорю о том уровне знаний грамматики, которое нужно для правильного построения речи. И это нужно человеку любой профессии, так что вопрос к школьному образованию.

В примере инверсия.  Смысловой разницы нет.

А зачем инверсия? Приведите пример.  Так разве говорят? Может, это некорректная инверсия?

Почему некорректная. Вы и сами знаете, для чего нужна инверсия. Что касается нашего примера, без контекста говорить о конкретном назначении инверсии сложно. Возможно для экспрессии, логического подчеркивания.
